# Create a query to return the average transaction of a clients orders

Tags: sql, sql-server, coldfusion

I would like to return the average order value ( sum of `Qty * Price` for all line items in an order then avg order totals) for a client in a financial year for a table that looks like the following

Financial Year Starts 1st/Jul/Year (can be passes in dynamically as a param)
Financial Year Ends 30th/Jun/Year (can be passed in dynamically as a param)
UserID (can be passed in Dynamically as a param)

```
Orders Table
-OrderID
-UserID
-OrderDate

OrderItems Table
-OrderItemID
-OrderID
-Qty
-Price
```

Scripting Language i am using is coldfusion and the db is MSSQL

Thanks All for your time

CHRIS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not familiar with coldfusion.

The SQL is

```
SELECT o.UserID, AVG(oi.OrderTotal) AverageOrderValue
FROM   Orders o
       INNER JOIN
       (SELECT OrderID, SUM(Qty*Price) OrderTotal
        FROM OrderItems
        GROUP BY OrderID) oi ON o.OrderID=oi.OrderID
WHERE  o.OrderDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this worked well. I had no idea where to start.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare 
@first_param datetime='01-01-2001'
@last_param datetime='01-07-2014'
begin

select AVG(orderid_cnt),sum_qty,a.user_id from (
select sum(b.qty*b.price) as sum_qty,orderid,COUNT(orderid) as orderid_cnt

From orders a 
inner join orderitems b
on a.orderid=b.orderid
group by orderid ) a 
inner join  orders a1
on  a.orderid=a1.orderid
```